# How to pass class name with model to the Django Admin site register?

Tags: python, django

I have a couple of models and I created some classes in `admin.py` for the `column` list view as below:

```
class AppleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
class OrangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
class BananaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
class GrapesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I'm trying to concatenate the `model` name with `Admin` (AppleAdmin) and pass the class name to the register parameter.

```
app_modules = apps.get_app_config('app').get_models()
for model in app_modules:
    ma = str(model.__name__+'Admin')
    if ma :
        try:
            admin.site.register(model, ma)
        except:
            pass
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would rather choose the [`@admin.register(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for model in app_models:
    admin_name = f"{model.__name__}Admin"
    admin_class = locals()[admin_name]
    try:
        admin.site.register(model, admin_class)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Comment: Getting error with `[modeladmin_name]`. Is it `[model.admin_name]`?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Still getting an error on this line `admin_class = locals()[model.admin_name]`. It says `AttributeError: type object 'SomeModelName' has no attribute 'admin_name'`

Comment: How do you get `app_models`? And will it work when you simply register the model in the loop `admin.site.register(model)`?

Comment: I just update my post